# iOS - Dropbox API : Get icon for videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, thumbnails, dropbox-api

I have images and videos stored on Dropbox. I can retrieve the thumbnails of the images. That's great, but if my metadata is a video, I don't have any thumbnails.

So how can I do to display the first image of the video without download the entire video ? (For waiting time and bandwidth).

Comment: See if this link can help you : https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2014/01/retrieving-thumbnails/

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a massively ideal solution for it... try this though http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone

Comment: Looking at their documentation for the /thumbnail call back it doesn't look like you actually can get it for a video; This method currently supports files with the following file extensions: "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "tiff", "tif", "gif", "bmp", "webp", and "wbmp".

Photos that are larger than 20MB in size won't be converted to a thumbnail.